# Как правильно отследить значение переменной?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть инпут (невидимый). Когда начинается ввод текста, событие кейпрес вызывает событие фокус на инпут, в который и передаеться все, что вводят с клавиатуры. дальше переменная "value_input" получает значение с ипнпута и происходит сравнение с базой.

Проблема в том, что все это запускается по событию кейпрес, то есть, например, если кто-то введет восемь символов, то будет восемь проверок в базе. А нужно сделать всего одну проверку. То есть, нужно знать, что ввод в инпут закончен, и тогда начинать проверку.

Как узнать, что ввод в инпут закончен, и тогда выполнить всего одну проверку?

Предположим, что для того, чтобы узнать, что ввод закончен, я написал функцию, но дальше проблема: как вызывать эту функцию?

Если функцию проверки вызывать при каждом событии кейпрес, то это не подходит, нужно только при первом.

Как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: _"Как узнать что ввод в инпут закончен"_ -- можно проверять input.value.length

Comment: ajax валидация так и происходит...при каждом "тыке". Только скорее `keyup` а не `keypress`....... еще можно на `blur` .. но нет гарантии что фокус с инпута уберется

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский При каждом мне не нужно. Это не обычная проверка нужно знать когда пользователь закончил ввод и только тогда сравнить. А не при каждом набранном символе.

Comment: @Dementiy1999 это невозможно. вы не знаете мыслей пользователя. Может он набирал. потом задумался. пошел чай попил, продолжил набирать. пошел в туалет. потом пришел передумал и всё стер и начал заново писать. потом пришла девушка и они занялись страстным секисом. а потом вспомнил что он не дозаполнил и не закончив прилюдии пошел дописал символы и отправил.........ставьте тогда `setTimeout` на проверку ввода тогда

Comment: @Dementiy1999 Могу вариант предложить, не знаю на сколько это безопасно: При обращении к странице с формой происходит обращение к БД, из которой вытягиваются нужные данные и складываются временно в некую сессионную переменную. При валидации сравнивается значение именно с данными в этой переменной, дергая лишь её.... после окончания работы с формой данные из той переменной надо будет очистить не забыть

Comment: @Dementiy1999 делай проверку `onblur`  либо при нажатии `enter` всё просто. Это самый частый вариант, когда пользователь заканчивает что-то делать.. либо переходит на другой элемент, либо отсылает форму по интеру.

Comment: Ну точно узнать что ввод окончен невозможно, если только пользователь не нажмёт Enter или сменит фокус с этого input'a . Можно после каждого кейпреса запускать таймер и если скажем в течении 2-5 секунд больше нет событий кейпрес то делать запрос

Answer (score 1):

Есть например такой замечательный js фреймворк [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)

У этого фреймворка есть сущность под названием Observables.

То что вы хотите сделать, делает "из коробки" с помощью этого фреймворка.

Рекомендую прочитать [это](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Так же советую посмотреть пример [HelloWorld](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html). По сути он делает то, что вам требуется.

Пример:

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>

// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

    this.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

Потыкать можно [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/78yot2cp/)

Comment: Так это ж обычная работа `onblur` или реакция на `enter`. А ТС нужно чтоб именно когда человек закончил набирать. А как узнать когда юзер закончил набирать?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы потыкали пример?

Comment: Конечно. Я что-то упустил? текст меняется только тогда когда уходит фокус.... или я по ентеру шлепнул....... о чем я написал выше... у же самую работу выполняют `onblur` и отлов кода ентера И подключать целый фреймвоооооорк для такой задачи - нерационально.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если вы потыкали, то могли заметить, что у вас текст внизу меняется, только когда вы сняли выделение с инпута. Так же если вы заглянули в документацию, там есть такая штука: `myViewModel.fullName.extend({ rateLimit: 50 });` Будет нотифицировать о изменении параметра каждые 50ms

Comment: Так я  о том и говорю. `onblur` не рациональнее вместо подключения фреймвооооооооорка? + поставить `setInterval`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в любом более менее приличном проекте как правило используется какой то MVVM фреймворк. Аналогичное можно реализовать с помощью большинства фреймворков. Какой вы используете?

Comment: Так весь вопрос в том.. узнать когда пользователь закончил набирать. А то что вы там собираетесь `нотифицировать о изменении параметра каждые 50ms` это не значит что пользователь ЗАКОНЧИЛ набирать. Как я писал уже.. человек просто мог уйти пить чай.... и что? значит он закончил? нет. И тогда ваша проверка нотификация по времени - будет неправильной, т.к. пошлет запрос к БД, который ТС не хочет делать. Будет равносильна тому, что юзер сонный тыкает медленно в клавиши.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в примере как раз происходит срабатывание, когда юзер закончил ввод.

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский, извините может не точно описал проблему. Я точно могу знать что пользователь ввел слово по тому что на ввод в форму ограниченное время. Событие кейпрес передает фокус на инпут и все попадает куда надо. Проблема в том как мне сделать что событие кейпрес запускало функцию ток один раз пока пользователь не введет слово. А не при нажатии каждой новой буквы.

Comment: @Dementiy1999 то, что ограничено по времени - это ничего не значит) Допустим ограничено время на 10 минут. он написал слово..пошел покурить. пришел довводил и уложился в это время..... но как бы то ни было, если совсем по простому, как я уже писал в комментариях к вашему вопросу - используйте не `keypress`, а проверку `onblur`(bygen теряет фокус) либо при нажатии `enter`